# iOS Swift 3 - Can't stop the UIActivityIndicatorView after submit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I have a submit button which submits email and password for validation through `HTTP` in `JSON` format, but indicator view does not stop even though the app receives the response from the server.

```
    @IBAction func signInButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let validated = validateEmailAddressTextField()
    if validated {
        let emailAddress = emailAddressTextField.text
        let password = passwordField.text

        let url:URL = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/app/user/signin")!
        let session = URLSession.shared

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let user = User(emailAddress: emailAddress!, password: password!)
        let requestJSON = careGiver.toJSON()

        request.httpBody = requestJSON?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
        indicator.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.startAnimating()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.0) {
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                (
                data, response, error) in

                guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
                let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(dataString)
                indicator.stopAnimating()
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

When I click 'submit' button, I see an indicator view on top of the button, but it doesn't stop and disappear.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

I am using `Swift 3` and `Xcode 8`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`indicator.stopAnimating()`

Try to run this line of code on the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works.. why do i need to call inside async block?

Comment: Cuz everything that interacts with the UI must be run on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Network closure is called on a random thread, but UI code must be handled in main thread only. So all you need is to call your indicator.stopAnimating() in the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Also I'd move this block to the beginning of the closure (before guard) to prevent continue of the animation in case of error in response.